# Javascript: The Good Parts - Why is - 1 being used here

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am merely just curious if he is using this to iterate over the entire array. i always had a feeling this is what -1 did but i want the correct answer since assuming will get me nowhere but mistakes. Appreciate any assistance.

```
m.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a === b) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(typeof a === typeof b) {
        return a < b ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return typeof a < typeof b ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: All JS sort functions return a negative number, positive number, or zero depending on how the two objects should be sorted. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Comparing 2 things (A and B) have 3 possible outputs. 
A is less than B (-1). 
A is equal to B (0). 
A is greater tha B (1).

Comment: yeah i shouldve gone to .sort section on mozilla but completely forgot. thanks for the responses, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is being used because sort expects the callback to indicate if a was less than (-1), equal to (0) or larger than (1)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort